# Configuration of Hibernate sessionFactory in Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

How can I configure hibernate `sessionFactory` in Spring such that it uses the `hibernate.cfg.xml` for configurations (instead of configurations settings in `applicationContext.xml`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />
```

Comment: I added this property to my bean definition (sessionFactory) in applicationContext.xml. Still it looks like it doesn't pick up the configuration from hibernate.cfg.xml. Actually I get 'ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.CacheProvider' where as I have specified for 'NoCacheProvider' in hibernate.cfg.xml.

Comment: I was using 'org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean'. When changed to 'hibernate4' instead of hibernate3 in the class name. It worked (rather moved to another error).